# Listing presentations at a conference side-meeting on a CV?

Tags: cv

At a recent conference, members of a working group were invited to give quick summaries of their research in a side meeting. Obviously these don't qualify as [peer reviewed conference activity](https://theprofessorisin.com/2016/08/19/dr-karens-rules-of-the-academic-cv/), but would it still be appropriate to include such a talk in the "other talks" portion of the CV?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I don't see why you couldn't include this, as long as it's clearly understood that you didn't present a peer-reviewed paper at that conference.